# :before element in back of parent element

Tags: html, css

I try to implement the following effect by using the `:before` but I have problem with the `z-index`.

[image]

My code is like this:

```css
.container {
  background : #FFF;
}

.item {
  background-position : 50% 50%;
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width : 200px;
  height :200px;
  position : relative;
}

.item:before {
  content  : '';
  position : absolute;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  right    : -20px;
  bottom   : -20px;
  border   : 2px solid #0AF;
  z-index  : -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200')"></div>
</div>
```

The problem now, is that the container seems to cover the `:before` element.

For the moment I don't mind about the "MIDDLE AGE" item.

How can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: Can you use `img` in html instead of `background`?

Comment: Nope, I should use the image as background in stylesheet.

Comment: Do you need that "container" have a background? if you remove it you will have your effect, otherwise, you could set `display: inline;` to the container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following **CSS styles**:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Code in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5cq5576k/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  background : #FFF;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item {
  background-position : 50% 50%;
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width : 200px;
  height :200px;
  position : relative;
}

.item-border {
  content  : '';
  position : absolute;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  right    : -20px;
  bottom   : -20px;
  border   : 2px solid #0AF;
  z-index  : -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-border"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&amp;txt=200%C3%97200&amp;w=200&amp;h=200')"></div>
</div>
```